Using IPTW weights inside a Bayesian brm() cox model
I am dealing with some IPTW data to compare 2 different treatments efficacy on a proportional cox hazard model and I need to use IPTW weights in the model but I cannot figure out how to use it in brms
Here a reproducible example: I can create a Bayesian coxph model with brms:
library(brms)

### use brms package dataframe
data("kidney")

### create random propensity scores to simulate the database
kidney$sw <- runif( nrow(kidney), min=0.5, max=2.5 )

### create the brm model
model <- brms::brm(
  time | cens(censored) ~ sex,
  data = kidney,
  family = cox()
)

and everything works fine. I searched how to implement weights and I found this post that uses this syntax:
brm(bf(outcome | weights(iptw) ~ treatment), data = whatever)

but this is relative to a linear model, not a cox() one, where if I try to add weights() it fails:
model <- brms::brm(
  time | cens(censored) | weights(sw) ~ sex,
  data = kidney,
  family = cox()
)


Error in eval(rhs(formula)[2], data, environment(formula)) : object 'sw' not found

I also tried:
model <- brms::brm(
  Surv( time, censored ) | weights(sw) ~ sex,
  data = kidney,
  family = cox()
)


Error in Ops.Surv(y, 0) : Invalid operation on a survival time

Does anybody have an idea of how to integrate weights in coxph brms?
